# Disable <private> in iOS unified logs, system wide

Tags: ios, logging

How can one disable iOS's substitution of strings with `<private>` in a system-wide nature? I'm trying to debug cross-process issue, and Apple's daemons appear to output useful logs, but all important info is replaced with `<private>`.

Comment: I have the same issue but only on iOS 11 beta. The logs from iOS 10 are visible. Is it the same for you?

Answer (score 1):

This was intentional on their part, Apple is super on top of privacy and therefore they build this logging functionality with that in mind.

When you send dynamic string (formatted yourself vs static strings) they replace the contents of the dynamic inputs with `<private>` - you can override this on a by parameter basis:

> • Privacy is handled on a parameter by parameter basis
>
> • Scalars and static strings are assumed to be public
>
> • Dynamic strings, collections, and objects are assumed to be private
>
> • Can be overridden on a per-parameter basis
>
> "%{public}@" or "%{private}d"

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/